# How can I find all the 'name' elements that begin with a specific string?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a personal project at the moment and ran into some trouble.

I'm using Beautiful Soup to scrape some user replies off a web page. I'd like to specifically scrape the number of downvotes and upvotes on their post but I haven't been able to successfully do so.

Below is the HTML that contains the number of upvotes for a user's post. Each user has a different `name` element ID as shown with the `171119643` so I have been confused as to how I can scrape for all the `name` elements.

```
<strong id="cmt_o_cnt_171119643" name="cmt_o_cnt_171119643">756</strong>
```

I did notice each name starts with the same string: `cmt_o_cnt_`. Is there a way I can scrape for elements starting with that string using the code below?

```
for url in soup.find_all('strong', name_=''):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-regex solution would be to check if the substring `"cmt_o_cnt_"` is in `tag['name']`:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    if "cmt_o_cnt_" in tag['name']:
        print(tag['name'])  # or do your stuff
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Could you clarify what you mean by the 'name' part of your code? What should I be inserting there?

Comment: I'm glad to help! Nothing should be inserted, it should be exactly like that. `tag['name']` is just a way of accessing the `name` attribute of `tag`.

Answer (score 0):

By using CSS Selectors, you can scrape the name elements that you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
  <strong id="cmt_o_cnt_171119643" name="cmt_o_cnt_171119643">756</strong>
  <strong id="cmt_o_cnt_171119644" name="cmt_o_cnt_171119644">256</strong>
  <strong id="cmt_o_cnt_171119645" name="cmt_o_cnt_171119645">123</strong>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
for tag in soup.select('strong[name*="cmt_o_cnt_"]'):
  print(tag['name'])
```

You can check some usages of css selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)